# Calculate the number of months remaining in months

Tags: excel, powerquery

I am trying to determine how many months remain between a finance end date and today but I keep getting an error.

`#"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Filtered Rows", "Payments Left", each Number.Round(Number.From(([fEndDate] - Date.From(DateTime.LocalNow()))/( 365.25 / 12 )) ,0 ))`

[image: Error shown from immediate window]

I am trying to avoid creating a new column with today's date if possible.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem with the information you have provided. No indication as to what the error is. Only a single line of code. No data (should be posted as text). Please edit your question after reading [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Something is wrong with fEndDate.  If you add a step prior to that step that adds a custom column =[fEndDate],  and then click that  step what does it show fEndDate to be equal to ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming it does what you want, your code generates numbers

```
x = Table.AddColumn(#"Filtered Rows", "Payments Left", each Number.Round(Number.From(([fEndDate] - Date.From(DateTime.LocalNow()))/( 365.25 / 12 )) ,0 ))
```

[image]

So now the question is, what is the full code you are using (which you get from home...advanced editor... and put into your question by editing it)  and what is the error you got?

Without seeing the error, I'll just assume one of these would be causing it: (a) prior step is not named **#"Filtered Rows"** (b) don't have a column named **fEndDate** (c) column **fEndDate** is not formatted as a date (d) column **fEndDate** does not contain dates

Comment: Apologies for the vagueness of my question and lack of information. i have updated my question with a screenshot form the immediate window

Comment: Looks to me like fEndDate is not formatted as a date field